# Average of Strings With 2 Decimal Points

Tags: c#, average

Using C#, I have 5 strings that are reading data from a temperature sensor on an Arduino board:

```
string currentTemp1 = serialPort1.ReadLine();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
string currentTemp2 = serialPort1.ReadLine();
Thread.Sleep(1000);..... and so on.
```

This is returning the values into the strings such as: 19.45, 19.45, 19.50, 19.45, 19.50.

I've tried a bit of research into trying to get the average, but am having problems working out how to convert the strings with the 2 decimal places into an Integer, and then getting the average.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you don't want to parse the strings into integers. You should use float/double/decimal instead:

```
var temp1 = float.Parse(currentTemp1);
var temp2 = float.Parse(currentTemp2);
var average = (temp1 + temp2) / 2;
```

Or, you could use a loop if there's a variable number of integers:

```
var temps = currentTemp1.Split(", ");
float total;
foreach (var t in temps)
{
    total += float.Parse(t);
}
var average = total / temps.Length;
```

Comment: Lacking other information about the problem, the example should use `decimal` rather than `float` since it offers the most precision.

Comment: How do I pass the 'average' back so that I can push the content into a textbox please?

Comment: @TheWoo: `return average.ToString()`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks very much for all of that.

Comment: agree with @EricJ. there will be precision error with float which will yield inconsistent results. Better to use decimal.

Comment: @Bharath @EricJ - In this case, the OP is working in temperature. Temperatures are a scientific measure and thus not accurate enough to be thrown off by the imprecision of `float` or `double`. `float` also offers better performance when working with large sets of data. Jon Skeet's answer to this question explains it best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Comment: +1 for clarifying with the link, thanks @justin niessner